# What is the easiest way to display an RSS-Feed on a Website with JQuery?

Tags: jquery, rss

I wanted to Display this RSS-Feed:

http://www.spiegel.de/thema/reisen_per_bahn/index.rss

on my website and I am thinking about the easiest way. JQuery came to my mind. How do I do that?

thanx in advance :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try http://www.zazar.net/developers/zrssfeed/

Comment: i looked to zazar.net. it is very simple.+1

Comment: thanx, I had it up and running in under 2 minutes!

Comment: per [Ian](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3122112/ian) , the updated url is http://www.zazar.net/developers/jquery/zrssfeed/